# How to detect any key press in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, dom-events

How do I detect any key press on Angular 2 (e.g. not necessarily in an input box)

Currently I managed to do this using the following code:

```
import {Component, HostListener} from "@angular/core";

@Component(<any>{
    selector: 'foo',
    template: `<h1>Foo</h1>`,
})
export class FooComponent {
    @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
    keypress(e: KeyboardEvent) {
        console.log("Key Up! " + e.key);
    }
}
```

The above code manages to work fine for most characters e.g. alphanumeric, punctuation, symbols, etc

The issue is that this method does not run when pressing keys such as SHIFT, CTRL, F1...F12, Tab, ALT etc.

Comment: Could be added to the answer (docu): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to use `('document:keydown')` instead of `('document:keypress')` to get shift, ctrl...

Comment: also useful to get Escape